# Getting inside of arrays in json / Alamofire [Swift]

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I am using Alamofire for getting json of: https://randomuser.me/api/
Is there any simple way to get inside those arrays in Swift? I was trying like:

```
        Alamofire.request(.GET,"https://randomuser.me/api/").responseJSON{
        (response) -> Void in
        if let json = response.result.value{
            print(json["results"]["user"]["name"])
        }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind using a library, I'd highly suggest [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON).

It's good to note that this library is **not** required and parsing JSON can be done with `NSJSONSerialization`.

Answer (score -1):

In Swift this is currently possible only with an extension / library.

Some libraries with this feature:

- [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)
- [In your case, maybe a perfect solution: SwiftyJSON and Alamofire combined](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/Alamofire-SwiftyJSON)

Otherwise you'd need to use the `NSJSONSterilization` and checking each variable with safe unwrapping.

Comment: "only with an extension / library."? Nono ;)